# Git merging forked repos

Tags: git

All,

So I am working with someone on a project, and I forked the repo they created for the project within an organization owned by them. So, I began to set up some stuff and successfully committed and pushed that to my forked version of the repo. But, the original version is still behind mine for obvious reasons. How would I 'push' my changes to the original repo, and also receive them when, for example, the person I am working with makes a change? I am asking here because I tried to set the upstream and push directly to that, but the perms blocked me out. But, as I understand it there is a way to do it with a forked repo of your own. Still new to this, so anything is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is it github we're talking about? Most git online services provide a way to make pull requests to another repo.

Comment: Yeah that seemed to do it. Not sure why it wasn't working before, but now I see you can do it through the GUI. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge their code into yours (or visa-versa), and either create a pull request or push your merged code into theirs.

Here's what it might generally look like:

1. Set up their repo as a remote (if it isn't already): `git remote add original ENDPOINT`
2. Pull their code into yours: `git pull original master`, or whatever you named them.
3. Fix any merge conflicts. After add and commit changes.
4. Push your code to their repo or create a pull request.